# Bump map is shoving only on one side of an object

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I've got some wooden planks, and the bump map is showing only on the side of the planks, but not on the whole plank. What do i Have to do to change that? Changing the direction of displace modifier to Z isn't helping.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think, the Image Texture needs a proper Vector as input for its coordinates. You might use the *Node Wrangler* Add-on and then hit *Ctrl* + *T* to create some automagically with your *Image Texture* Node selected.

Comment: I tried that, didn't change anything..the bump map still shows only on the side of the plank

Comment: Have you tried out the different Output Vectors of the *Texture Coordinate* node? Like Generated, Object, UV, ... (for UV it might help you out to UV-unwrap your Planks first - *U* in *Edit mode*).